# How to resolve Socket timeout exception in mi phones for network calling?

Tags: android

I am testing my application in Mi phones so the APi is not working but in other phones application works correctly.

Comment: Yes it is working in browser,postman and other android phones

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue in past. The reason is your phone's internet data has Ipv6 connection but your server has not enable Ipv6.

if you want to check. Go to your Phone setting. Select sim which has mobile data enabled. then open Access Points and change APN protocol & APN Roaming Protocol to Ipv4.

If it start working then your server does not have Ipv6 configuration or may be something wrong with enabling it.

Hope it help.

Comment: I am using Wifi not the phone internet data what will i do?

Comment: Sorry but No idea about that.. when i faced this issue at that time its working on wifi but not working on devices.